# What is the red angle if the green and blue angles are known and the yellow angles are equal in the following image?

Tags: angle, reflection

What is the red angle if the green and blue angles are known and the yellow angles are equal in the following image:

[image]

Edit: What's the formula for figuring out the red angle?

Comment: You will need the mirror matrix for your problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_rotations_and_reflections

Comment: Are you asking for $R=2B-G-180^o$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $R,G,B,Y$ be red, green, blue, yellow respectively. Then

$$R+\pi = B+Y, \quad B = Y + G.$$

Rearrange to represent $R$ in $B$ and $G$ only.

Comment: I assume this is in in radians? If i switch out PI with 180degrees it will yield the same result in degrees?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$